# Is there a "short" format specifier for an ISO 8601 time and offset without fractional seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting, iso8601

Is there a "short[er]" format specifier for an [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation without the [optional] fractional seconds?

That is, given

```
var n = DateTimeOffset.Now;

// short "s" format  -  2014-02-14T10:41:49
n.ToString("s")
// short "o" format  -  2014-02-14T10:41:49.7200222-08:00
n.ToString("o")

// desired output
// custom format    -  2014-02-14T10:41:49-08:30
n.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

is there a "short[er]" format specifier for the last case?

---

*Context clarification:* I'm using the formats primarily with `string.Format`, where the long format can quickly muddle a format string.

Comment: It seems you already accomplished what you need with the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz` format string.  What problem do you have?

Comment: @wdosanjos As asked, I was wondering if there is a shorter standard format specifier that I am overlooking :) `string.Format("..{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}..{1:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz}..", ..)` becomes "ugly" to look rather quickly.

Comment: @wdosanjos Of course, the answer might quite simply be "no".. or "no, but you could.."

Comment: Possibly `string.Format("{0:s}{0:zzz}", DateTime.Now)`

Comment: Would `n.ToString("szzz")` work? That could be a nice short solution.

Comment: @Raidri "szzz" results in "42-08:00", in this case "s" seems to be the Julian day (?) or, not the short format whatever it is. That would have been neat, though.

Comment: @wdosanjos That does indeed work in a `string.Format` context. It's shorter anyway..

Comment: -3 - if anyone would care to explain why, it'd be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, misunderstood the question the first time around. IMHO an extension method would work the best:

```
class Program {    
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToCustomString());
    }
}

static class DateHelper {
    public static string ToCustomString(this DateTimeOffset time) {
        return time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

you need to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` otherwise `CurrentCulture` will be used which will substitute `:` for the user's current regional time component separator which may not be a colon, and that would result in a non ISO 8601-compliant string.

If you need to use it in longer strings with multiple substitution fields maybe look into [custom format providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.getformat(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I don't understand the "truncate" bit. The custom format specifier does work, but seems needless long. It's hard to get variables into format strings (as with `string.Format`), although I guess I could always use a utility method or variable and `ToString` prior-to usage in such case...

Comment: It should not seem long, just write a custom extension method.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't a built-in standard format in .NET - it's crazy, because this is the exact format that works best with HTML5's `<time>` element, for example. The closest thing is the round-trip format `"o"` but that includes fractional seconds which we don't want. No other built-in standard format automatically includes the `zzz` specifier needed when working with `DateTimeOffset`.